# Failed to create view. Unknown TVF: myFunc

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create a view in BigQuery that contains a javascript UDF (myFunc).  The query works fine when run in the console with either the UDF inline or referencing a URI in Google Cloud Storage.  However, when trying to save the query as a view using either reference I get the error:

```
Failed to create view. Unknown TVF: myFunc
```

Is there any way to save a view in BigQuery that uses a UDF?  I haven't used the REST API, but it appears it may be possible to include both a view.query and externalDataConfiguration.sourceUris[] property in the request based on the data structure in the [documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Fixed! See Thomas's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34300525/1375400).

---

Currently it's not possible to create a view that uses a UDF. We'd like to add support for this functionality in the future though.

Comment: Under Thomas' answer I commented on the availability of this fix in Datalab, would you kindly look into this as well, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

this was an issue with the UI that we recently fixed.  You should now be able to run a query that uses a UDF, and then click "Save View" to persist that query as a view as you would expect.

If you're using `mk` in the command-line tool, you would specify the UDF resources used by your view via the `--view_udf_resource` flag.

Hope this helps, thanks!

Comment: This solution does not seem to work on Datalab: %%bigquery execute --target project:dataset.tablename --query querymodule still returns error.

Comment: Is there any plan on making this available on Google Cloud Datalab? Otherwise what is the recommended way to create new table from complex query in Datalab?

Comment: I'd suggest asking the Datalab folks directly. https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/resources/support If it suits your use case, you can always create the view + UDF outside of Datalab and then reference it from within Datalab.