# Using Google Datalab, how to create table from a complex query with UDF in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I have seen many similar questions, but they are not specific to Google Cloud Datalab AND using UDF at the same time, e.g. [query execution shows Unknown TVS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619955/failed-to-create-view-unknown-tvf-myfunc/32620508) and [creating table from query result via python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622526/google-bigquery-create-a-table-from-a-query-result).

I managed to create the table when UDF was not used, but when it was, it returned error "Unknown TVF: myFunc".

**Edit**
Here is the code I'm using:

```
%%bigquery udf --module transform_field
...udf function...
```

Then I used udf function above in an sql query:

```
%%sql --module querymodule
...complex SELECT query FROM transform_field(table)...
```

Then I'd like to use that query to create another table as shown below:

```
%%bigquery execute --target project:dataset.tablename --query querymodule
```

But it kept showing this error instead:

> Unknown TVF: TRANSFORM_FIELD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I found it. Turns out you need to pass the query through a python cell before using it in a `%%bigquery execute` cell:

```
bq_query = bq.Query(querymodule, udf=transform_field)
```

---

Thus the entire process should go as follows:

```
%%bigquery udf --module transform_field
...udf function...
```

Then I used udf function above in an sql query:

```
%%sql --module querymodule
...complex SELECT query FROM transform_field(table)...
```

Then use the query and udf function above to create a `bq.Query` object.

```
bq_query = bq.Query(querymodule, udf=transform_field)
```

Then use `bq_query` in table creation.

```
%%bigquery execute --target project:dataset.tablename --query bq_query
```

I keep being amazed at what good night sleeps do.

Comment: Great! As an additional resource, there is an entry on UDF in the Datalab wiki with a working example: https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/wiki/UDFs